# Importar datos de CSV a base de datos desde MVC5 mediante un formulario

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y en este momento necesito importar datos de un archivos CSV "Excel" Delimitado por comas (,) cierta información, necesito que mediante un formulario puedan subir el excel y que dicho excel se importe automaticamente en la tabla `dbo.Collaborators` estoy usando MVC5 y SQL Server 2014.

Mi vista es la siguiente:

```
@model SI_OldMutual.Models.Collaborators

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UploadPlanta";
}

<h2>UploadPlanta</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="planta" /><br />
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Cargar" />
    </div>
}
```

Parte de mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
private SI_OldMutualContext db = new SI_OldMutualContext();

//  UploadPlanta
public ActionResult UploadPlanta()
{
    return View();
}

//POST UploadPlanta
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadPlanta([Bind(Include = "planta")] Collaborators collaborators)
{
    return View();
}
```

Parte de mi modelo:

```
[Key]
public int CollaboratorID { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Codigo")]
public string codigo { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Cedula")]
public string cedula { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Nombres")]
public string nombres { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Fecha Ingreso")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime fecha_ingreso { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Salario Basico")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal salario_basico { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Salario Cargo")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal salario_cargo { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Regimen")]
public string regimen { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Tipo de Contrato")]
public string tipo_contrato { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Ciudad")]
public string ciudad { get; set; }
```

**Explicacion:** necesito que mediante dicho formulario puedan insertar el archivo CSV delimitado por comas y al momento de darle cargar automáticamente la información que esta en dicho archivo se importe en la tabla `Collaborators` correspondiente al modelo.

He estado revisando varios ejemplos en grupos de internet y de StackOverFlow pero no doy con un ejemplo claro con respecto a lo que necesito, cualquier aporte es de bastante utilidad.

Cabe destacar que estoy usando MVC5 en visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo primero, es recibir en el Controller el archivo que has subido, guardarlo en el servidor, leerlo con Linq y almacenarlo en base de datos:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPlanta(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //Guardado del archivo en el server
            string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), _FileName);
            file.SaveAs(_path);

            //Leemos el CSV y lo pasamos a una lista
            List<Collaborators> listaColaboradores = (from p in File.ReadAllLines(_path)
                                    let parts = p.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                    select new Collaborators 
                                    {
                                        CollaboratorID = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]),
                                        codigo = parts[1],
                                        cedula = parts[2],
                                        nombres = parts[3],
                                        fecha_ingreso = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[4]),
                                        salario_basico = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[5]),
                                        salario_cargo = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[6]),
                                        regimen = parts[7],
                                        tipo_contrato = parts[8],
                                        ciudad = parts[9]
                                    }).ToList();

            //Guardamos toda la información de esa lista en base de datos
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                foreach(var colaborador in listaColaboradores){
                    context.Collaborators.Add(colaborador);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "El archivo se subió y procesó correctamente";
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error procesando la información: " + ex.Message;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Toma en cuenta que al leer el archivo, cada `part[X]` va a ir mapeando a una columna del CSV, esa parte la tienes que ajustar dependiendo del diseño del archivo CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede trabajar en 2 partes

1. Cargar el archivo al servidor

aquí un ejemplo de controlador

```
using System;  
usingSystem.Collections.Generic;  
using System.IO;  
usingSystem.Linq;  
usingSystem.Web;  
usingSystem.Web.Mvc;  
namespaceFileUpload.Controllers  
{  
    public class UploadController: Controller  
    {  
        // GET: Upload  
        publicActionResult Index()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
        [HttpGet]  
        publicActionResultUploadFile()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
        [HttpPost]  
        publicActionResultUploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
                {  
                    string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
                    string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);  
                    file.SaveAs(_path);  
                }  
                ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";  
                return View();  
            }  
            catch  
            {  
                ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";  
                return View();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Aquí ejemplo de la vista

```
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "UploadFile";  
}  

<h2>UploadFile</h2>  

@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadFile","Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))  
{  

    <div>  
        @Html.TextBox("file", "", new {  type= "file"}) <br />  

        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />  

        @ViewBag.Message  

    </div>  


}
```

Aqui tienes un tutorial bastante claro:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Una vez hayas subido el archivo, con esta instrucción TSQL lo puedes cargar en tu tabla

```
BULK INSERT SchoolsTemp
    FROM 'C:\CSVData\Schools.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

Por supuesto debes ajustarlo a tu archivo, tabla y estructura del csv

Saludos,

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, efectivamente ya he intentado con esa instrucción pero lamentablemente no me funciona, por otro lado cuando copies un codigo por favor percatate de que este bien escrito, sin embargo no me funciono.

Comment: amigo, no te puedo pasar el código exacto para lo que necesitas, te pase un link en donde esta, para que revises.

Comment: Hola, ya estuve revisando la documentacion pero igual me genera error.