# Como cargar un excel y mostrar sus datos En C# (MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

He investigado en la web la forma de cargar un archivo excel desde un:

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Luego de cargar tratarlo en y pasarlo a una lista (esto no me importa) solo quiero saber como puedo leerlo desde el archivo cargado en el input. No encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Los ejemplos que he visto lo usan desde la ruta, es decir, solo cargan las cadena mas no el archivo

Comment: Agrega el código de backend que has intentado :D

Comment: Los codigos que he visto (todos) son usando la ruta del archivo excel no el  archivo como tal, por eso no tengo idea de como empezar. @fredyfx

Comment: Perfecto, entendido :D cuando se necesitan ideas para empezar, se requiere afinar los criterios de búsqueda, revisa este enlace: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=read+excel+aspnet+mvc luego de un esfuerzo de lectura y haber intentado programar algo, te ayudamos con todo el gusto del mundo. Espero tomes a bien el comentario. Saludos :D

Comment: Bro, siempre es bueno agotar todas las fuentes durante tu investigación. Mira, en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73135/importar-datos-de-csv-a-base-de-datos-desde-mvc5-mediante-un-formulario) hacen lo que tu quieres pero con un archivo CSV, échale un vistazo y saca dudas más concretas para que te podamos echar la mano :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este ejemplo me ayudo a solucionar.

http://techbrij.com/read-excel-xls-xlsx-asp-net-mvc-upload

Answer (score 0):

Hay una libreria llamada NPOI para .NET que procesa documentos Excel.

http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/05/read-xlsx-data-for-npoi/

El input tipo FILE, guarda el archivo en un directorio temporal. Por lo tanto, debes obtener el path del fichero y utilizar la libreria NPOI para procesar el fichero Excel y mostrar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

En asp.net mvc el archivo se envia mediante POST a un action en el parametro definido como `HttpPostedFileBase`

[Upload and download files using ASP.NET MVC](http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp.net-mvc/)

[ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF 6 - Working With Files](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files)

observaras en los ejemplos como se hace uso de

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
  //codigo
}
```

al realizar el submit del form el file que selecciones en el

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

se asignara a ese parametro, un detalle observa que el `name` del input coincide con el del parametro del action.

De esta forma tendras el excel en el servidor para que puedas trabajarlo.

Si usas la liberia [ClosedXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML) podrias cargar el excel desde un Stream, hay mucha info

[ClosedXml wiki](http://ClosedXML)

entonces obtienes el stream usando

```
MemoryStream excelStream = new MemoryStream();
file.InputStream.CopyTo(excelStream);
```

para asignar este en el constructor de `XLWorkbook`